# Qtip on fullcalendar agendaweek view

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, qtip, qtip2

I have a fullcalendar implementation where Qtip is used to display a tooltip when an event is clicked, through the eventRender callback, as follows:

```
eventRender: function(event, element) {
    element.qtip({
        content: {
            text: 'Hello world'
        },
        position: {
            my: 'left center',
            at: 'right center'
        },
        show: {
            solo: true,
            event: 'click'
        },
        hide: 'click unfocus'
    });
},
```

How would one go about displaying a tooltip on an empty slot when it is clicked in agendaweek (or agendaday) views?

I have tried using Qtip in both the dayClick and select callbacks to no avail - I can find no way to make a tooltip show next to the cell that was clicked as neither of these callbacks have the element variable to assign the qtip to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an "empty slot" you will want to use dayClick instead of eventRender - because that's for events already in the calendar.

So using your example my dayClick would look like this:

```
dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {
            $(this).qtip({
                content: {
                    text: 'Hello world'
                },
                position: {
                    target: [jsEvent.pageX,jsEvent.pageY]
                },
                show: {
                    ready: true,
                    solo: true
                },
                hide: 'unfocus'
            });
        }
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer; it works fine in the month view although the vertical position of the qtip is incrrect in the agenda views, as shown in this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/moqovy1s/2/

Is there any way to correct the positioning?

Comment: I have changed the position to target the mouse click. You should be able to just add target: 'mouse' but for whatever reason that wasn't working. Also note this probably won't work in fullcalendar 1.5. I would recommend using version 2 if you can. See http://qtip2.com/options#position for more details and examples on positioning.

Comment: I'd tried with target: mouse which was obviously the problem. Using the jsEvent co-ordinates works fine. Thanks!